# Issue in managing Tab states using Fragment and FragmentActivity for android.support.v4 library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I have worked on TabActivity in last project and I manage all the states, but now TabActivity is deprecated so I decided to use Fragment and FrameActivity with Tabs using android.support.v4 library to support lower versions of android,

I just studied Documentation of Fragment and "FragmentBasics" Sample ([Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)) and "Support4Demos" sdk-sample but i have an issue with managing tab states.

I have one Launcher Activity MainActivity and I have added five tabs in it using FragmentTabHost and five Fragments (i.e f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) in each particular FragmentActivity, initially I have set tab1 as currentTab

[image]

Now i click on NewPage that replace the Fragment with 6th Fragment (f6) using interface just like given in Support4Demos(FragmentTabs.java)

[image]

Now I click on second tab, so it will display second Fragment(f2) which I set for second tab in MainActivity, but it is overlapped, f6 overlaps f2.

[image]

then I click on tab1 again so it would display f2 and then I clicked back button application crashes.

on back button i set getSupportFragmentManager().popBackstack();

If i just click on back press without moving on TAB2 then it works fine.